# regexp_substr String Length

Tags: oracle10g, birt

I am having an issue with the maximum number of expressions for an "IN" clause. Basically I had originally..

```
WHERE X IN (1, 2, 3...1001);
```

However this caused an error, since you can only have 1000 expressions in the IN clause. So I decided to swap it into a table. I'm being passed a CSV value of the expressions (e.g. "1, 2, 3...") that I can use to split it up and insert into a temporary table.

However this change resulted in my having a new issue, the regexp_substr function as a limit on the length of the string you can pass (I believe 512 bytes). Here is some sample code for how I am doing this...

```
SELECT * FROM dual 
WHERE X IN (SELECT regexp_substr('1, 2,..., 1001', '[^,]+', 1, level) 
FROM dual 
CONNECT BY regexp_substr('1, 2,..., 1001', '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL)
```

I feel like I might be trying to smash a square peg into a circular hole. Is there a better method of dealing with this excessively long string? I'm considering using JavaScript to split the string into more manageable parts and pass it one at a time instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are two obvious alternatives.

I guess you read https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement.
The first alternative is from a comment on that page:

instead of

```
where t.X in (1, 2, 3, ..., 1001)
```

you could use

```
where instr ('|1|2|3|...|1001|', '|' || t.X || '|') > 0
```

Note the leading and trailing '|' on both arguments.

Be warned, though, that this simple approach cannot benefit from an

```
create index t_x on t(X).
```

Thus, unless you have other good restrictions, you'll end with a full table scan.

The second approach is to create a function split_func with a signature more ore less like this

```
function split_func 
( pi_csv in varchar2
, pi_separator in varchar2 default ','
, pi_trim in varchar2 default 'Y' 
  -- Y/N, because boolean is not allowed for functions in SQL
)
return SYS.ODCIVarchar2List PIPELINED; 
-- SYS.ODCIVarchar2List is a varray of varchar2(4000)
```

I'll leave the actual coding as an exercise for the reader.

Then you can use that function like this (assuming that your column X is a number):

```
with search_values as 
(
  select to_number(column_value) as n
  from table (split_func ('1,2,3,...,1001'))
)
select t.* 
from t, search_values
where t.X = search_values.n;
```

If your column t has an index on X, this query can use it.

Btw an overloaded function with pi_csv in clob would make sense as well.